# Choose duplication vs. string based variable (object property) creation

Tags: php

I have code like this:

```php
$something_type = $this->db
    ->where('something_type_id', $something->something_type_id)
    ->get('something_types')
    ->row();
if(!$something_type) {
  $something->type = lang('data_not_specified');
} else {
  $something->type = $something_type->something_type_name;
}

// everything is exactly the same here except for one word
$something_category = $this->db
    ->where('something_category_id', $something->something_category_id)
    ->get('something_categories')
    ->row();
if(!$something_category) {
  $something->category = lang('data_not_specified');
} else {
  $something->category = $something_category->something_category_name;
}

...

// and so on, about four times
```

One solution I thought of was:

```php
$classfications = array('type', 'category');
foreach ($classifications as $classification) {
  $id_property = "something_{$classificiation}_id";
  $something_classification = $this->db
      ->where("something_{$classification}_id", $something->$id_property)
      ->get("something_{$classification}s")
      ->row();
  if(!$something_classification) {
    $something->$classification = lang('data_not_specified');
  } else {
    $name_property = "something_{$classificiation}_name";
    $something->$classification = $something_classification->$name_property;
  }  
}
```

Of course, reading that will probably result in someone having the fits, so what do I do about this? This is probably a very common problem but I can't name it so having trouble Googling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [Inflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection)?

The biggest challenge with the code snippet in the question is that the classifications you have provided have different pluralized forms (e.g., "type" becomes "types", yet "category" becomes "categories"). In order to structure this data without inflection, you could create a nested array hash, e.g.,

```
$classifications = array(
  'type' => array(
    'plural' => 'something_types',
    'id'    => 'something_type_id',
  ),
  // etc.
);

foreach ($classifications as $singular => $data) {
  /*
   * Produces:
   * $singluar = 'type';
   * $data['plural'] = 'something_types';
   * $data['id'] = 'something_type_id';
   */
}
```

However, most of the PHP frameworks I have used include an *Inflector* class (or similar) to handle the nuances in language that make using singular and plural names together problematic (and would avoid the need for a nested data structure, as described above).

Have a look at [CodeIgniter's Inflector Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/inflector_helper.html) to get an idea of what this entails. If you are already using a framework (your use of a `$db` helper suggests you might be) then also be sure to see if it supports [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), which handles this kind of scenario automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Inflection is a great tool, I forgot about that; though this addresses a problem I'm yet to consider about, the question I intend to ask is: 'if you were coding this, would the array/iterate approach look sensible to you, or would you stick with all the repitition'?